# Redux Thunk - Get Updated Store in Promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm having an issue trying to use Redux Thunk for implementing JWT Authentication in my app: when I perform login and retrieve the promise from the action, I do not get the updated store (I still have the previous value).

Here is my code:

```
const Login = ({ doLogin, token }) => {

const submitForm = (e) => {
        doLogin(email, password).then(function () {
            console.log(token);
        });
    }
};
return (
    // Some JSX that calls submitForm()
);
};

Login.propTypes = {
    token: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    doLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        token: state.auth.access_token,
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = { doLogin };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Here is my action creator:

```
export function doLogin(email, password) {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(start());
    return axios
        .post(config.api.url + "/login", {
            email,
            password,
        })
        .then((success_rsp) => {
            if (success_rsp.data.success) {
                dispatch(success(success_rsp.data.access_token));
            } else {
                dispatch(error());
            }
        })
        .catch((error_rsp) => dispatch(error()));
};

function start() {
    return { type: types.AUTH_LOGIN };
}
function success(access_token) {
    return {
        type: types.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        is_authenticated: true,
        access_token: access_token
    };
}
function error() {
    return {
        type: types.AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR,
    };
}
}
```

And here is my reducer:

```
const authReducer = (state = initialState.auth, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case types.AUTH_LOGIN:
        return {
            ...state,
            is_loading: true,
        };

    case types.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            is_loading: false,
            is_authenticated: action.is_authenticated,
            access_token: action.access_token
        };

    case types.AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR:
        return {
            ...state,
            is_loading: false,
            is_authenticated: false,
            access_token: "",
        };

    default:
        return state;
}
};
```

The problem is that when I get in the Promise of my `Login` component, it logs the previous value of the token, and not the one received by the API.

However, when I log the `state` in the `mapStateToProps` function, I see that the function is called 3 times in total (one when arriving on the page, one when starting the doLogin, and one on the success), and it logs the right value for the token.

Do you know why the token I get is not updated? And how I could get an updated one?

Thank you!

Comment: Could it be the level of your `initialState.auth`? You are assigning values directly to ‘state‘ at first sight..

Comment: @ibubi thank you for your answer. I think what I am trying to do is wrong. I just found another way to do what I want: added a `useEffect` function which logs the token when the component is reloaded, and it does load the right token (in the end). I believe I should not do it inside a Promise, but inside the useEffect, with the right checks. (it makes sense because the promise has no reason to wait for the state update)